# Generate a saml 2.0 assertion

Tags: java, saml-2.0

We need to generate a saml 2.0 assertion from an application in java, we are trying to make use of opensaml. The sending to the service provider must be done through http post binding. Are there any examples of this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can used openSAML, more details here[1] but as well as you can used WSO2 Identity Server[2] as well. It is opensource and latest version in IS 5.3.0.
 
If you like to use WSO2 Identity Server,first you need to create service provider for your web app(SAML Assertion consumer app). You can found sample web app call travelocity.com here[3] and you can follow the steps for service provider creation here[4].

[1] http://www.capcourse.com/Library/OpenSAML/index.html
[2] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/
[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Downloading+a+Sample
[4] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Single+Sign-On#ConfiguringSingleSign-On-ConfiguringtheSSOwebapplication

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check